# Display top 5 sales and bottom 5 sales in the same query

Tags: oracle

I want to display the top 5 sales and the bottom 5 sales in the same query in Oracle, not in PL/SQL.

Comment: What version of oracle?

Answer (score 2):

According to your question you might want the following output.

```
SQL>DESC tbl_sales
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SALES                          NUMBER

SQL> SELECT * FROM tbl_sales;

     SALES
----------
     1
     2
     4
     3
     5
     6

6 rows selected.

SQL> WITH t1 AS (
  select sales, row_number() over (order by sales desc) rn
  from tbl_sales 
),
t2 AS (
  select sales,row_number() over (order by sales asc) rn
  from tbl_sales
)
select t1.sales as "Top 5", t2.sales as "Min 5"
from t1 join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn where  t1.rn<=5; 

     Top 5  Min 5
---------- ----------
     6      1
     5      2
     4      3
     3      4
     2      5
```

Answer (score 0):

I used PostgreSQL to answer this question, but the principle should be the same. There's no need to use CTEs to solve this problem.

First I generated a sample table with random values for a 100 fields.

```
CREATE TABLE sales AS
SELECT s, 
       trunc(random() * 100000 + 1) AS sales_amount, 
       random_string(10) AS vendor, 
       trunc(random() * 100 + 1) AS vendor_rating
FROM generate_series(1, 100) s;
```

Which generates 100 records of the form

```
"s";    "sales_amount";          "vendor";       "vendor_rating"
----    ---------------    ---------------       ---------------
  1;             98274;      "ULbPPdUTRR";                   59
```

So, I then ran the query

```
(SELECT *, 'Top 10' FROM sales
ORDER BY sales_amount DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *, 'Bottom 10' FROM sales
ORDER BY sales_amount ASC
LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY sales_amount DESC;
```

which gives the required result, without CTEs. This makes it portable to MySQL for example. Note the use of the strings 'Top 10' and 'Bottom 10' - this little "trick" makes it easy to identify which record belongs to which category.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `LIMIT` syntax. The principle may be the same but how does that answer the question?

Comment: SQLFiddle was and still is down. Site is there but I can't create a simple table. I'll put in the Oracle syntax when it's back up.